# how to calibrate bno055 gyro sensor?

Tags: java, robotics

For our FTC Robot, we are trying to calibrate BNO055 gyro sensor and there is already a [TeleOp](https://github.com/FIRST-Tech-Challenge/SkyStone/blob/ca9a9696559f895f2efd285ea2b0fa984ad16048/FtcRobotController/src/main/java/org/firstinspires/ftc/robotcontroller/external/samples/SensorBNO055IMUCalibration.java#L74) under external/examples.

I am wondering if we need to calibrate on every field or do only once?

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to calibrate the gyro one time. Then press on the a button to save that configuration. Make sure that in your code you link to that calibrated gyro file by adding,

```
// Set the parameters for the gyro
params = new BNO055IMU.Parameters();
params.angleUnit           = BNO055IMU.AngleUnit.DEGREES;
params.accelUnit           = BNO055IMU.AccelUnit.METERS_PERSEC_PERSEC;
params.calibrationDataFile = "BNO055IMUCalibration.json"; // Make sure that you have run the calibrate teleop first!!
params.loggingEnabled      = true;
params.loggingTag          = "IMU";
params.accelerationIntegrationAlgorithm = new JustLoggingAccelerationIntegrator();

// Init the IMU make sure it is in the configuration on the phone as I2C BUS 0 named as imu
BNO055IMU imu = hardwareMap.get(BNO055IMU.class, "imu");
imu.initialize(params);

// Let the gyro initialize 
while(!isStopRequested() && imu.isGyroCalibrated()) {
    sleep(50);
    idle();
}
```